How to download recent YouTube livestream — dash segments fragments?
If I try to download a livestream that has recently finished, yt-dlp tries to make a http request for each fragment and gets rate limited by YouTube.
I have to cancel, and retry the command multiple times. How to fix?
C:\Users\tynda\Downloads>yt-dlp -f 140 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UQ12Y-XxRRM
[youtube] Extracting URL: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UQ12Y-XxRRM
[youtube] UQ12Y-XxRRM: Downloading webpage
[youtube] UQ12Y-XxRRM: Downloading ios player API JSON
[youtube] UQ12Y-XxRRM: Downloading mweb player API JSON
[youtube] UQ12Y-XxRRM: Downloading MPD manifest
[info] UQ12Y-XxRRM: Downloading 1 format(s): 140
[dashsegments] Total fragments: 3983
[download] Destination: Ask Us Anything： Wrapping Up 2024 & Big Announcements For 2025! [UQ12Y-XxRRM].m4a
[download]   8.1% of ~ 162.14MiB at  281.45KiB/s ETA 08:56 (frag 322/3983)[download] Got error: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden. Retrying fragment 323 (1/10)...
[download] Got error: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden. Retrying fragment 323 (2/10)...
[download] Got error: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden. Retrying fragment 323 (3/10)...
[download] Got error: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden. Retrying fragment 323 (4/10)...
[download] Got error: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden. Retrying fragment 323 (5/10)...


Upgrading to 2024.12.13 fixed this for me
